# Bank account set up for me

Tags: scams

I received an email this morning from SeNs @scb.com - Standard Chartered Bank. An
Account # 3102892372 in the 
Amount of 16,300,000.00 was opened yesterday in my name. I am to contact Account Officer by the name of
Ken Roberts at kenroberts@standardchartered.X10.bz or kenroberts60@yandex.com and give him my personal banking information so a transfer of funds can take place. This is
other email address listed as origin of the email - info@yilmazguneadana.org. Is this a scam?

Comment: *Anything* that asks for your *"personal banking information"* is a scam.

Comment: What do **you** think? Do you know somebody who would just give you 16+ million $$$ for no return?

Comment: I suppose this question is worth dignifying with a response if it truly prevents someone from falling into this trap, but at the same time, it's hard for me to believe someone could be this gullible and could ask this question from a genuine heart.. especially given that there are so many questions on the site just like it. In fact, I think this one is even more far-fetched than most of the others I've seen.

Comment: Send me a wire transfer for only 1% of that amount and I'll tell you for sure.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that, even if you merely reply (or click something in the email): sure, **you're likely not silly enough to literally fall for the scam as such**...  But merely replying, or clicking something in the email, instantly puts you on a **(scammer's) list of known, operating, fresh emails**, which brings endless hassles, spam, and targetted malware/trojan type attacks.

Answer (score 6):

***Here we go again!***

Why, oh *why*, would someone just open a bank account in your name with that much money for no good reason?  Unless there's a very rich relative in your family tree, this can not come to a good ending.  Besides, if this was money being left to you by someone as part of an inheritance, you'd hear from attorneys from the estate.

Notwithstanding everything @NickR posted about the details of what makes it suspicious, ask yourself why a banker would contact you by email about an account with this much money in it.  The bank would, at the very **least**, send you a registered/certified letter on official stationery.

So what happens here is when you give them your banking information, whoever it is that's doing this will clean out your account, and that's for starters.   They will ask for enough information to steal your identity too, and if you have good credit, that'll be gone in a heartbeat.

The best scams (meaning the most successful ones) always appeal to peoples' greed, using large amounts of money that just miraculously belong to the victim, if only they'd give a little information to "transfer" the money.

Worse yet, most of these scams will come up with some kind of "fee", "tax" or other expense that you have to pre-pay in order to make the transfer happen, so this just adds insult to injury when you find out (the hard way!) you've been scammed.

**DO NOT** reply to the email you received or, if you already have, don't send any more responses.  If they think they may have you on the hook then they won't stop trying, and it will become very messy very quickly.

**THIS IS NOT REAL MONEY**!  It isn't yours, it doesn't really exist, and all it will do is come to no good end if you go *any* further with it.

Stay safe, my friend.

Answer (score 3):

First note that Standard Chartered Bank's domain is "sc.com", not "scb.com".

The "scb.com" site appears to be an architecture company "of sorts".

The "yandex" email address is for a Russian search company which offers free email services.

The "standardchartered.X10.bz" email address is clearly a spoof use of the standard chartered name, and is registered in Belize - a small central American country and tax haven.

The "yilmazguneadana.org" is not recognised by internet DNS, so appears to be an email only service.

This is clearly a phishing scam.  Do not respond to this email.  Of the many thousands of people that have received this email, sadly some will be dumb enough to respond - the elderly are most vulnerable to this type of scam.

Comment: Note it is trivial to forge the from address [Send spoofed emails with telnet](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/send-spoofed-emails-with-telnet/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a scam. There is no money. They are after your personal details so that they can get your money.

Answer (score -2):

If you must play with these scammers, be sure to open a new account, at a new bank, in order to supply "personal banking information".  If it does pan out and they give you some money, you can always move it to your real bank account.

Be sure to deposit into the new account no more than you're willing to lose to them.